# How can I get the left-side menu back?

Tags: interface

The left-side menu disappeared suddenly (the one with the paint bucket tool, brushes, eraser, etc.).

[image]

How do I get this view back?

[image]

Comment: Press "T" on the keyboard

Comment: WAT. That fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome! [Blender Default Keymap](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/keymap/blender_default.html)

Answer (score 2):

In the right upper left corner of window, there is a small black button with grey arrow along the side. Click on it to reveal the toolbar.

[image: description]